# Rails: Eager load association with trackable_type in scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, associations, eager-loading

This is a hard one.

I have an `Activity` model:

```rb
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :trackable, polymorphic: true
    scope :include_all, -> { includes(:trackable) }
    ...
end
```

So if I do:

```rb
@activities = Activity.include_all
```

The code above is working well, but what if I want to also eager load the parents of the trackable record? Also those models have different parents:

`Answer` model:

```rb
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :question
    has_many :activities, as: :trackable
    scope :include_all, -> { includes(:question) }
    ...
end
```

`Post` model:

```rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :blog
    has_many :activities, as: :trackable
    scope :include_all, -> { includes(:blog) }
    ...
end
```

`Category` model:

```rb
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :activities, as: :trackable
    scope :include_all, -> {}
    ...
end
```

Note that the `include_all` scope in each model show the associations to include. I have tried

```rb
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
    scope :include_all, -> { includes(trackable: :question) }
    ...
end
```

This will broke when an `Activity` with `trackable_type` = `Post` appear.

Any ideas?

---

Rick's answer is a very nice aproach but, is there a way to use the association scope inside another scope? This can came very handy for associations with no parents like `Category`.

Something like

```rb
scope :include_all, -> { includes(trackable -> { include_all } ) }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define an additional `parent` association on `Answer` and `Post` to extend the interface of your `trackable` ducktype:

```rb
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: :Question, foreign_key: :question_id
  ...
end
```

```rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :blog
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: :Blog, foreign_key: :blog_id
  ...
end
```

```rb
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :include_all, -> { includes(trackable: :parent) }
  ...
end
```

Comment: Your idea is great assuming all models has parents, but what if there are some which don't? I'll update my question.

Answer (score 1):

Nailed it! If you add the scope directly to the `belongs_to` line, the associations will load with that scope.

```rb
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :trackable, -> { include_all } , polymorphic: true
    ...
end
```

Comment: Glad you were able to figure out a solution that fit your use case!

Comment: Thanks! Also I believe is a better solution, less code and more flexibility ;)